# How to append a div to another using only PHP

Tags: php, html

What I'm trying to do here is to add/append a div inside another using only PHP here's an exmple :

```
<div class="display_errors">                       
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactNameFieldError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <p>blah blah 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>             
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactEmailFieldError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
           <p>blah blah 2</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactEmailFieldError2">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <p>blah blah 3</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactMessageTextareaError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <<p>blah blah 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

And i want to append a div inside `display_errors` div like this :

```
<div class="display_errors">                       
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactNameFieldError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <p>blah blah 0</p>
        </div>
    </div>             
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactNameFieldError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <p>blah blah 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>             
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactEmailFieldError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
           <p>blah blah 2</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactEmailFieldError2">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <p>blah blah 3</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactMessageTextareaError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <<p>blah blah 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Here's what I have tried and unfortunately didn't work!!

```
$search = '<div class="display_errors">';
$replace = '<div class="display_errors">                       
    <div class="formValidationError" id="contactNameFieldError">
        <div class="small-notification red-notification no-bottom">
            <p>blah blah 0</p>
        </div>
    </div>';
$content = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
```

Any errors in my code ? Much appreciated.

Comment: well, the html DOES have a syntax error, `<<p>blah blah4`, but str_replace couldn't care less about that. if it's not finding your display_errors tag, then whatever's in $content does NOT contain that extact string. e.g. maybe it's really `&lt;div class=...`

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution, it may not be *that* super, but it will work.
Another possible way would be to read the main div as xml and manipulate it with the xml-methods, where you have much more flexible ways to edit the html.

But if this is the only thing you will to, it might work ;)